# Rails app deploy with rubber - error in create_staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services, capistrano

rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3
I want to deploy a simple rails app to aws, vulcanized with complete_passenger_nginx_postgresql
placed aws key, secret and account in rubber.yml

During cap rubber:create_staging, I get an error, and I don't know its source and how to investigate. Would love your suggestions.

- 2013-02-02 21:46:17 executing `rubber:setup_local_aliases'
  /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb:92:in`block (3 levels) in load': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/instance.rb:188:in `each'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/instance.rb:188:in`each'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in`instance_eval'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in`invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in`method_missing'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:383:in`post_refresh'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:242:in `create_instances'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:29:in`block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in`invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in`execute_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in`block in define_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/utils.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in load'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in`instance_eval'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in`invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in`find_and_execute_task'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in`each'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in`execute_requested_actions_with_help'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in`execute'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.1/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/cap:19:in`load'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
  from /Users/yanivpreiss/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'

Answer (score 1):

`rubber:setup_local_aliases` seems to be the source of the problem so perhaps you haven't set something correctly in your rubber.yml file.
Forgot to set `domain name` perhaps?
Moreover I tried deploying yesterday with `complete_unicorn_nginx_postgresql` and HAproxy was having some issues in the port binding with nginx_unicorn, so be careful with those.

Comment: The domain name is ok, will go over the rest of the values again, thanks